# hide cells border using css

Tags: css, border

I want to hide border of cell of a table . [image]

How to do it using css ?
As it shows, I need to hide the marked borders (as in third and second rows).

Comment: Can you post the HTML and CSS you have for the table with the second and third rows hidden? Maybe then we can figure out why it's not working for the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<style>
table {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width:100%;
}
table tr {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
table th {
    border: none;
}
</style>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="col1">1</th>
      <th class="col2">2</th>
      <th class="col3">3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</thead>
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/AhHFP/

Comment: I am playing with `td`, not with `th`

Comment: Does that make any difference?

Comment: Uh, I mean, have you tried changing `th` to `td`? I don't have no IE at hand here, but it works for me in fx.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
border-collapse:collapse;
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
td.col1
{ 

   border-left:0px;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
table {
border: 1px solid black;
width:100%;
border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm assuming thats a table? without markup, its kinda hard but set your table to table{border-collapse: collapse;}
http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/border-collapse